# What the scope operator ( :: ) do in the class name

Tags: c++, class

I found the following class declaration hard to understand:

```
class App::Impl
```

Is the class name now App::Impl? What does the scope operator `::` do in the class name?

Comment: It was named `Pointer to implementation`, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl for more details.

Comment: This is simply **declaring** that the class `Impl` exists in the namespace `App`. It is not **defining** the class, but that's fine if you only need to use a reference or pointer to it. You can search for this with the phrase "forward declaration".

Comment: Since you call `::` the "scope operator" you likely have some knowledge of what it does already. If you can present an example of where you do understand what it does, then it may be helpful to use that as an analogy to show that it does exactly the same thing here.

Comment: @Cid FWIW, it looks like a decent question to me too (and naturally, I haven't downvoted it).

Comment: @hvd I agree that's a decent question, well, he might have done some searches to find out what the `::` are in a class declaration, but well, at least he's not asking for us to write some code for him. He just needed some explanation about something.

Comment: Not down voter - but the downvote button is there for questions "that are not useful, unclear, or lack research effort"... I would guess that in this case, it's a lack of research effort that people are going with.

Comment: I was led to this question by searching this issue on Google. So this question is actually useful for the people doing the research effort :-)

Answer (score 3):

The Scope Resolution Operator(::) is used to identify and specify the context to which an identifier refers. So here `App` refers to the namespace to which the class `Impl` belongs to. We can have different classes having same name by sub-scoping them in different namespaces. In such situations we need to specify the namespace of the class.

```
namespace X{
    class Name {}; 
} 
namespace Y{
    class Name {}; 
}
```

Here we can use `X::Name` and `Y::Name`

Answer (score 1):

In C++ `::` is the [Scope Resolution Operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-resolution-operator-in-c/). It is used to tell the compiler what [namespace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/namespace-in-c/) or class something belongs to.

In this case, `App::Impl` tells the compiler you are talking about the `Impl` that belongs to `App`.

Answer (score 1):

App is the NameSpace of that class you called Impl that can be defined in more NameSpaces with differences .